# Visual Studio(2015) stuck at the first step when creating C++ new project

Tags: c++, installation, visual-studio-2015

[image]

As shows in the screenshot, when creating a visual c++ new project, it got stuck at the first step, after clicking "OK", instead of going to the next step, this window popups up again and no c++ new project will be created. There is however no problem for creating c# project.

The OS is windows 7 and I have tried with Visual Studio 2015 as well as Visaul Studio Express 2015 for windows desktop, they both work fine with c# but have this problem with c++.

Any suggestions will be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Never seen this before, what troubleshooting did you do? Reboot pc? Do you have writing permission in the folder you use to write your project? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes, I have writing permission of the folder. I have reboot the pc and installed the express version when the original doesn't work. Should I delete them all and reinstall? The visual C++ was first not included in the Visual Studio and I have extra installed it when I try to creat a c++ project using the tool VS provided.

Comment: Yes, I think reïnstall is your best option...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after uninstall all versions of Visual Studio on my Laptop and reinstall the Visual Studio 2015 express for desktop.